Is there a way to deploy a docker-compose app without showing the source code
I have a Python application that runs through a Docker Compose. I have multiple images that run Python and JavaScript scripts. I would like to know if there is a way to deploy my application locally on another computer, without giving access to the code to the third party.
For now, the simplest way I have seen is to deploy it on a server (like AWS ECS), but I am looking for a way to deploy it locally.
Thank you!

"locally on another computer" that's an oxymoron

This question is not really about docker. Being a Python code, it is visible by definition. Even packaging with the available tools, such as pyinstaller, won't make it unreadable by someone who really wants to view the source code

Thanks for the answer @DeepSpace
Do you have an idea of ​​the language or tool to use I can use to achieve my objective?
Thanks

Go, Rust, C++, Haskell, or another language that compiles to machine code will be much harder to decompile.  Java, Erlang, Elixir, or another bytecode language are only somewhat harder (I've found decompiled Java bytecode fairly readable) but at least there you're not truly distributing the source.

Since the other comments haven't said it explicitly: anything you include in a Docker image is very easy to get back out.  For Python (or JavaScript or Ruby or another scripting language) you must have the source code to run it, which means the source code must be in the image, which means anyone who has the image can easily get it back.

Thanks for the explanation @DavidMaze !

Correction: for Python one doesn´t need the "source code" - just the compiled bytecode files, as stored in __pycache__:  a container image could easily be created with only these files, and the app would run. However, for "secret keeping" purposes that does no good, as it is easily inferrable (and there are "decompiler tools" available, just as for Java bytecode)
